# Stopping com.mysql.mysqld from launching over and over and over agin

Tags: launchd, mysql, oracle

System messages are showing repeated

```
Dec 25 14:42:02 ROLANDs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

every one of two seconds. I think this is being started by com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.

Using 'sudo launchctl remove' on both of these doesn't seem to work as after a restart they're both back, so there must be something else happening (Murphy Corollary: before you can do anything, there's something else you have to do first).

I have MySQL mysql-5.7.25-macos10.14-x86_64 loaded on the my Macbook Pro and in System Preferences it's being started on bootup.

How do I fix this issue ... I'd like to upgrade, but don't want to take this problem forward with the upgrade.

Thanks!
Roland

Answer (score 1):

The script gets reloaded at boot because of [`RunAtLoad`](https://www.launchd.info/#key-RunAtLoad) flag set to `true` in its plist.

Try `unload`ing the script with following command, so it doesn't get picked up again.

```sh
sudo launchctl unload -w </path/to/com.mysql.mysql.plist>
```

I don't have MySQL installed, so I can't tell exact location of the plist. Generally, it should be in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`.

If not, look into following locations also and replace path in command:

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`
- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`